# What's the name of flutter widget that has icons bellow the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

What's the name of the Flutter widget that has icons below the screen and I can slide to right and left to change between these screens (Ex: Twitter main page)

[image: I want to make my main page with those four icons like this image]

I could create a `Container` with a `Row` and the `Icons` and do this manually, but I suspect that already exists this widget on Flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this bottom navigation bar can be done using `BottomNavigationBar` in the `bottomNavigationBar` property on your `Scaffold` :

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.business), label: 'Business'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.school), label: 'School'),
    ],
  ),
```

and for the slidable pages can be done using a `PageView` widget:

```
PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
    ScreenOne(),
    ScreenTwo(),
    ScreenThree(),
  ],
);
```

and you can link both of them when you click an item in the `BottomNavigationBar`, it will navigate to a specific page with a `PageController`.